# Vietnamese character in .NET Console Application (UTF-8)

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8, console-application

I'm trying to write down a UTF-8 string (Vietnamese) into C# Console but no success. I'm running on Windows 7.

I tried to use the `Encoding` class that convert `string` to `char[]` to `byte[]` and then to String, but no help, the string is input directly from the database.

Here is some example

> Tôi tên là Đức, cuộc sống thật vui vẻ
>   tuyệt vời

It does not show the special character like `Đ` or `ứ`... instead it show up `?`, much worse than with the Encoding class.

Does anyone can try this out or know about this problem?

---

My code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XDataContext _new = new XDataContext();
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
    string srcString = _new.Posts.First().TITLE;

    Console.WriteLine(srcString);
    // Convert the UTF-16 encoded source string to UTF-8 and ASCII.
    byte[] utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(srcString);
    byte[] asciiString = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(srcString);

    // Write the UTF-8 and ASCII encoded byte arrays. 
    Console.WriteLine("UTF-8  Bytes: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(utf8String));
    Console.WriteLine("ASCII  Bytes: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(asciiString));


    // Convert UTF-8 and ASCII encoded bytes back to UTF-16 encoded  
    // string and write.
    Console.WriteLine("UTF-8  Text : {0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8String));
    Console.WriteLine("ASCII  Text : {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciiString));

    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8String));
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciiString));
}
```

and here is the outstanding output

```
NhÃ  bÃ¡o Ä‘i há»™i bÃ¡o XuÃ¢n
UTF-8  Bytes: 4E-68-C3-A0-20-62-C3-A1-6F-20-C4-91-69-20-68-E1-BB-99-69-20-62-C3-
A1-6F-20-58-75-C3-A2-6E
ASCII  Bytes: 4E-68-3F-20-62-3F-6F-20-3F-69-20-68-3F-69-20-62-3F-6F-20-58-75-3F-
6E
UTF-8  Text : NhÃ  bÃ¡o Ä‘i há»™i bÃ¡o XuÃ¢n
ASCII  Text : Nh? b?o ?i h?i b?o Xu?n
NhÃ  bÃ¡o Ä‘i há»™i bÃ¡o XuÃ¢n
Nh? b?o ?i h?i b?o Xu?n


Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Setting the output encoding to UTF8 should work: `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8`. Are you sure that the problem is not from the way you are reading the text from the database? If you put a breakpoint in your code, is `srcString` encoded correctly?

Comment: yes, the breakpoint output is 100% fine. I'm considering moving to windows form but i dont need that much fancy feature in this case. :( too bad for winconsole

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetConsoleOutputCP(uint wCodePageID);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Console.WriteLine("tést, тест, τεστ, ←↑→↓∏∑√∞①②③④, Bài viết chọn lọc");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the output (use Consolas or another font that has all the above characters):

[image: proof]

Comment: The font is crucial. I tried the code and I got garbage encoding at first, so I didn't expect a font switch to make a difference, but it did.

Comment: It seems that `SetConsoleOutputCP` is no longer necessary to get this to work - perhaps something got fixed in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set `Console.OutputEncoding` to match `UTF-8`.

Probably something like:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: I've added the example. It's not working at all, my Console.OutputEncoding is a bit different that yours but it work the same way. I tried yours too, still the same

Comment: thanks how to use this into httpclient i'm facing issue :(
i tried like this not working for me
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("charset", "utf-16"));

Answer (score 0):

Does the font you use in the Console window support the characters you are trying to display?

Comment: I did not set the font, but it seam luicida can't show UTF8? is there anyway i can change it on-the-fly with C#?

Answer (score -1):

it is the problem with cmd.exe console. It doesn't support unicode. [Nothing to do with C#/.NET]

Try changing it to a GUI app if you can or write to a file.

Comment: But it has only limited fonts support. For example I can't output in Tamil, although I have unicode fonts for that language in the OS. That's what I meant by doesn't support unicode.

Comment: I think it only supports monospaced fonts, and probably (not sure!) doesn't do right-to-left properly, but it should be able to do Tamil if you find a monospaced font with Tamil characters. I tried DejaVu and it doesn't seem to have them.